# C# CRUD - Insert Erro (Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, crud

Bom dia,Tinha conseguido fazer tudo certo até este erro ao inserir algo na base de dados.
localhost/phpmyadmin - xampp.

É algo com o `id_user` mas não sei oque é. Eu no Insert não uso nem uma `txtbox` nem `combobox` para o `id_user` porque não sei que valor tenho que dar para ele.
Oque fazer?

Codigo e prints abaixo!

Estou preso aqui 2 dias e não sei como resolver.

*NOTA* se for perciso mais INFO eu dou.

[image: Erro ao Inserir na BD]
[image: Form]
[image: Tabela registos - Relation View]
[image: Tabela registos e as suas colunas]
[image: Tabela users e as suas colunas]

Codigo Inserir>

```
    private void btt_inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string Conexao_BD = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=tempos;SslMode = none;";

            string Query = "INSERT INTO `registos`(`id_registo`, `data`, `id_tipo`, `id_tec`, `id_user`, `id_processo`, `id_tarefa`, `horas`, `comentarios`) VALUES (NULL,'" + datatp_1.Text + "','" + comboBox_tipo1.Text + "','" + comboBox_tec1.Text + "','" + txt_teste.Text + "','" + comboBox_pro1.Text + "','" + comboBox_passos1.Text + "','" + txt_horas1.Text + "','" + txt_com1.Text + "')";

            MySqlConnection CONEXAO_BD2 = new MySqlConnection(Conexao_BD);
            MySqlCommand Comando2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, CONEXAO_BD2);
            MySqlDataReader Ler_BD2;
            CONEXAO_BD2.Open();
            Ler_BD2 = Comando2.ExecuteReader();     
            msg.Inserir();


            CONEXAO_BD2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Resumidamente a mensagem diz que você está tentando inserir um item em `registos` que não está informando o `id_user` ou está informando um `id_user` inválido (que não existe na tabela `users`). Vi que você está obtendo essa informação de `txt_teste.Text`, certifique-se de que esse campo esteja passando um valor válido.

Comment: Sim, foi isso mas eu resolvi metendo o valor do ID, seja 1(para user) ou 2(para admin) mas agora apareceu o mesmo erro mas com a combobox_tipo1 A dos Tipos! E nao sei porque nem como resolver isso. E gostava de saber como e se podia elimnar a id_users porque eu tenho ela mas nao uso

Comment: Você **entendeu** o problema anterior? Se você não precisa, seria só apagar essa coluna da tabela no banco e passar a não declará-la mais nas suas instruções.

Comment: O problema é que quando tento apagar a coluna id_user da tabela registos da este erro: https://imgur.com/a/jsZkKO2

Comment: Onde apago isso na Relation View?

Comment: Eu não sei dizer. Sinto muito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo o seu problema está na sintaxe de sua Query. Não atribua valor a ids que são auto-increment em seu INSERT.

Aconselho que você tente executar a Query na mão para ser mais simples de resolver o problema. Feche sua IDE por enquanto e tente realizar um cadastro manualmente. Existe varias alternativas: através do Console, MySQL Workbench ou diretamente do phpmyadmin que certamente será mais simples para você. [Como executar SQL no phpmyadmin?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c50g_RXPZo)

1 - Conserte sua query pois ela está errada.

2 - Implemente a query em seu programa.

3 - Aconselho de verdade que crie uma classe para gerenciar melhor sua conexão com o banco de dados.

Obedeça as boas praticas de programação:

- Variáveis ou atributos devem ser declaradas com sua primeira letra minuscula.

> Está errado: string Conexao_BD = "";string Query = "";
>
> O correto é: conexaoBD e query. A utilização de letra maiúscula
>   indevidamente faz com que sua IDE não identifique facilmente o que
>   são as coisas em seu código. Métodos e Classe com letra maiúscula e
>   atributos com letra minuscula.

- Crie uma classe para gerenciar sua conexão com o Banco de Dados.
  Você não precisa está criando um client e fechando a cada botão em que clicar. Alem de torna difícil a leitura do código dependendo da situação seu programa pode ficar mais pesado tanto em tamanho em disco quanto na execução na memoria RAM.
- Leia o erro isso ajuda muito!
  Talvez o inglês complique um pouco mas é só ir no google tradutor.

> Erro: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>       ('tempos'.'registos', CONSTRAINT 'registosjbfkl' FOREIGN KEY ('id.useO 
>       REFERENCES users' ('id.user') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>
> Erro PT: Não é possível adicionar ou atualizar uma linha filho: uma restrição de chave estrangeira falha ('tempos'. 'Registros', CONSTRAINT 'debatejbfkl' CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA ('id.useO REFERENCES usuários' ('id.user') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**Palavra de Motivação pra você! rsrs**
E o mais importante de tudo é nunca desistir. As vezes você passa horas ou dias para resolver um problema e acaba resolvendo depois em uma fração de segundos. Descanse a mente, não se estrese você está estagiando e sua obrigação é aprender então se divirta com os problemas que te passarem. Se tiver se sentido extresado vai tomar uma água e descansa um pouco a mente. Você está aprendendo e no final das contas o melhor professor é você mesmo.

Em programação a pratica fala mais alto. Leia códigos de programas simples que você tem desejo de criar no *GitHub*. Observe a organização das classes e a forma que eles utilização a orientação a objeto. Um código na qual o desenvolvedor sabe usar bem a orientação a objeto torna o código mais legível e facilita em muito a manutenção posteriormente.